# Implement xml files instead of resx files For Localization

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net5

I have a loclization tag but I want to use xml resources instead of resx files like nop comerce use I also want to implement some kind of caching system so I can load the key values pairs at launch of website.

```
public abstract class NopRazorPage<TModel> : Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorPage<TModel>
{
    private ILocalizationService _localizationService;
    private Localizer _localizer;

// <summary>
/// Get a localized resources
/// </summary>
public Localizer T
{
   get
        {
           

            if (_localizer == null)
            {
                _localizer = (format, args) =>
                {
                    var resFormat = _localizationService.GetResourceAsync(format).Result;
                    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(resFormat))
                    {
                        return new LocalizedString(format);
                    }
                    return new LocalizedString((args == null || args.Length == 0)
                        ? resFormat
                        : string.Format(resFormat, args));
                };
            }
            return _localizer;
        }
    }
}
```

So my question is to parts

1. How do i implement simple Xml file to use with above.
2. What is my best method or tooling to use for caching above as this would be used on rendering of the cshtml page

The usage of above is it should auto detect the language chosen by the user.

```
 <h1>@T("Search")</h1>
```

Comment: Hi @rogue39nin, what about using `XLocalizer` in asp.net core?

Comment: Thank you @Rena for mentioning `XLocalizer`, just want to add the docs link for [XLocalizer and XML localization setup](https://docs.ziyad.info/en/XLocalizer/v1.0/setup-xml.md)

Comment: Thats not what I want to achieve am wanting to deriev form a database not xml files

Comment: So the question is not clear enough. BTW, XLocalizer supports DB as well.